# Polling multiple Git repos for changes from the same Jenkins build plan

Tags: git, jenkins

My build setup looks like this:

- Multiple Git repositories that contain the source code, one per *module*.
- One master *build* Git repo that has scripts to a) clone the above repos in a directory structure, b) install dependencies and compile all of the modules, and c) run the unit tests in all of the modules.

In my Jenkins build plan, I would like to always check out the latest version of the *build* repo and then run the `setup.sh` script in the checked out folder. This works fine using Jenkins, I can trigger the build manually or poll the *build* repo for changes.

Since people are checking in code changes primarily in the module repos, I would like to trigger the Jenkins build when code is changed either in the *build* repo or one of the module repos. In either case, I want the same steps to be run:

- Clone the lastest version of the build repo
- Run `./setup.sh` in the build workspace folder

I know that I can add more than one Git repo to the build plan, but from what I understand, the build plan is then going to check out the changed project only. How can I force Jenkins to always clone the *build* repo if there are changes in one of the repos?

(Note: The above scenario works fine in Bamboo, where you can define multiple *Source Repositories* per plan, and then define which one is used for checking out the sources as part of the build job. I would like to replicate this behavior in Jenkins.)

Comment: Are you saying that running build.sh will behave differently depending on your module repos? Maybe this will help https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin

Comment: No, the `build.sh` script will always do the exact same thing. I want the same build plan (in the same directory structure) to be run when one of the repos in question changes.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Well, kind of. I used the multiple SCM plugin to define the various Git repos, and then used the "Check out to a sub-directory" in each repo's definition to point to the correct directory. Then in the script part of the plan, I kick of the central "build script" that again updates all of the individual Git repos one by one.